# Why won't my mouse and keyboard work in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, mouse, startup, freeze

I am clearly not the only one dealing with this... After upgrading to 10.10 my keyboard and mouse don't work at the login screen. However, if i plug in another mouse to a random USB port, they somehow come to life and everything works as a charm.

Does anyone know what causes this to happen? Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: what brand and model are your keyboard and mouse? and what brand and model is the mouse you plugged in that did work? (also are you on a laptop or PC?)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).